# Synthesized Methods for Class Extension Unavailable

Tags: objective-c

OK, I'm confused. I have a class Employee, that I declare several properties for, which of course, synthesize and work fine. But in the implementation class, I extend the class like so:

```
@interface Employee ()
    @property (nonatomic) unsigned int employeeId;
@end
```

which I would think would allow me to do the following in main.m:

```
Employee emp = [[Employee alloc] init];
//use some other property accessor methods...
[emp setEmployeeId:123456];

//do some other stuff...
```

But the compiler chokes on the use of `setEmployeeId` with the following error `"No visible interface for 'Employee' declares the selector 'setEmployeeId.'`

Can anyone tell me why I shouldn't be able to use the extension the same way I'd use the other properties? Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your `employeeId` property is 'private' if you have declared it using an continuation category in the .m file of your class. This means the compiler won't 'see' the definition during compilation - hence the array.

Technically, you could still access it at runtime using KVC, but you should really decide if the property should be public or private.

If you're testing / messing around then you can redeclare the property in a local category to make it visible during compilation.

Comment: Yes, it is *only* about visibility (I got that wrong in my answer). You can even define the class extension in a separate header file and include that wherever you need it.